# Kali linux no wlan0 interface

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, wlan, airmon-ng, aircrack-ng

When I run Kali Linux on Virtual Box and run the airmon-ng command, I get an error message:
**ls: cannot access /sys/class/ieee80211/: No such file or directory**
and no interfaces are shown. My wifi internal card works fine as I can access the internet.

Comment: Please see if this helps http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/191819/167583 and report back to us.

Comment: If your system is running inside a virtual machine, it will usually use a virtual (wired) network adapter - rather than accessing the interface hardware of the host system directly

Comment: @JuliePelletier i tried it but still it wont recognize wlan0 interface

Comment: You mention it's a "wifi internal card".  The [Kali "Troubleshooting Wireless Drivers" page](https://docs.kali.org/installation/troubleshooting-wireless-driver-issues) says that only USB wifi cards are supported in a VM.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a USB wifi adapter then do the following:

1) In the VirtualBox menu go to Devices > USB > select your wifi adapter

2) Wait as windows will install this virtualbox usb device and it will configure with your Kali Linux. At this point you will lose internet connection on the host machine (Windows in my case)

3) type in 'iwconfig' into the Linux terminal and you should see your wlan0 listed. success!