# After installing/booting kali linux, I can't connect to wifi. It says no wifi adapter found

Tags: kali-linux

I just bought a new HP laptop just for the purpose of installing and learning Kali linux. It had originally windows 10 installed in it. I downloaded and installed the latest version of kali linux. Everything seems to be good and working but when I tried to connect to internet, I can't to it. I can just connect using wired connection. For wireless connection, it says no wifi adapter found. I did not install kali on any virtual machine, my pc is a pure kali linux now straight booted in the drive.

When I type iwconfig in the terminal, it just shows me eth0 and lo. It doesn't show wlan0. I tried looking for solution for a whole day now. I tried a method, "download compact wireless" that everyone was showing, I was able to get wlan0 and wlan1, but now the problem is it doesn't detect any wifi. Also when I reboot my laptop, it is gone and I have to do it again, its not saved.

I have also realised that bluetooth is also not working. However, the download compact wireless method seems to fix the bluetooth, but ita gone at restart. There are people who said I need to get an adapter, but the laptop should have build in wifi card right? And I directly booted up in the machine, not in any virtual box, so do I really need to buy one? Whats the point of me buying a new laptop just for Kali? Please help me.

Comment: Add some detail of the HP laptop model ?

Comment: There is little point buying a laptop to learn Kali. It's usually run as a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

It is very unlikely that your HP laptop has a Kali Linux supported WIFI adapter.

Here is a list of some chipsets supported by Kali Linux

- Atheros AR9271
- Ralink RT3070
- Ralink RT3572
- Realtek 8187L (Wireless G adapters)
- Realtek RTL8812AU (newly in 2017)

You can find more details in this article

https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/buy-best-wireless-network-adapter-for-wi-fi-hacking-2019-0178550/

Answer (score 0):

Kali doesn't ship with proprietary wifi drivers, I've found someone with the same problem [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164433/how-can-i-install-wi-fi-drivers-in-kali-linux), try following some of these steps.

> You could try
>
> apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi
>
> modprobe -r iwlwifi; modprobe iwlwifi

Answer (score 0):

Nearly all of hp laptops have this issue , it's the wifi adapter which only has one antenna and so you need to install a different firmware. I have to do it again and again so I made a script. Plug an Ethernet connection using USB tethering and

make a file fixwifi.sh using

```
nano fixwifi.sh
```

Copy the contents

```
apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r) git build-essential dkms
git clone git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sudo modprobe rtl8723de
echo "options rtl8723de ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf
```

Save the file with

```
Ctrl+s and Ctrl+x
```

Execute it using

```
chmod +x fixwifi.sh && ./fixwifi.sh
```

and you are good to go.